# Is there a shortcut key for reformatting code in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I paste a piece of code in Google Colab, it always does not look good as its original format.

Is there a shortcut key for reformatting or automatically formatting code so that it might be clean and easy to read, such as PEP-style?